# Can Azure Service Bus Relay be used to expose an ASP.NET hosted WCF service?

Tags: asp.net, wcf, azure, azure-servicebusrelay

I'm working on a project where an ASP.NET WCF Service is hosted on-premises, and it needs to be exposed for use by other applications that are hosted in Microsoft Azure.

Azure Service Bus Relay is the desired method to expose the ASP.NET WCF service to the applications that are hosted within Azure. However, all the Azure documentation only show examples of setting up Service Bus Relay with a WCF service being hosted within a Console app.

Is it possible to host a WCF service within an ASP.NET application on IIS and have it exposed through Azure Service Bus Relay?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Sidney Andrews](https://twitter.com/sidney_andrews) posted an example at the following link of how to Configure the ASP.NET web.config file to setup the WCF service with the Service Bus Relay Endpoint.

https://gist.github.com/SidneyAndrewsOpsgility/bc1096ac96401f95b3d7

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2"/>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ServiceBusBehavior">
          <transportClientEndpointBehavior>
            <tokenProvider>
              <sharedAccessSignature keyName="RootManageSharedAccessKey" key="[replace with your key]" />
            </tokenProvider>
          </transportClientEndpointBehavior>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
    <services>
      <service name="WcfTest.Services.ClockService">
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="DefaultBinding" contract="WcfTest.Services.IClockService"/>
        <endpoint address="sb://[replace with your namespace].servicebus.windows.net/clock" binding="netTcpRelayBinding" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBusBehavior" contract="WcfTest.Services.IClockService"/>
      </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="DefaultBinding" />
      </basicHttpBinding>
      <netTcpRelayBinding>
        <binding name="ServiceBusBinding" />
      </netTcpRelayBinding>
    </bindings>
    <extensions>
      <!-- In this extension section we are introducing all known service bus extensions. User can remove the ones they don't need. -->
      <behaviorExtensions>
        <add name="connectionStatusBehavior"
          type="Microsoft.ServiceBus.Configuration.ConnectionStatusElement, Microsoft.ServiceBus, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <add name="transportClientEndpointBehavior"
          type="Microsoft.ServiceBus.Configuration.TransportClientEndpointBehaviorElement, Microsoft.ServiceBus, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <add name="serviceRegistrySettings"
          type="Microsoft.ServiceBus.Configuration.ServiceRegistrySettingsElement, Microsoft.ServiceBus, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
      </behaviorExtensions>
      <bindingElementExtensions>
        <add name="netMessagingTransport"
          type="Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Configuration.NetMessagingTransportExtensionElement, Microsoft.ServiceBus,  Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <add name="tcpRelayTransport"
          type="Microsoft.ServiceBus.Configuration.TcpRelayTransportElement, Microsoft.ServiceBus, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <add name="httpRelayTransport"
          type="Microsoft.ServiceBus.Configuration.HttpRelayTransportElement, Microsoft.ServiceBus, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <add name="httpsRelayTransport"
          type="Microsoft.ServiceBus.Configuration.HttpsRelayTransportElement, Microsoft.ServiceBus, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <add name="onewayRelayTransport"
          type="Microsoft.ServiceBus.Configuration.RelayedOnewayTransportElement, Microsoft.ServiceBus, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
      </bindingElementExtensions>
      <bindingExtensions>
        <add name="basicHttpRelayBinding"
          type="Microsoft.ServiceBus.Configuration.BasicHttpRelayBindingCollectionElement, Microsoft.ServiceBus, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <add name="webHttpRelayBinding"
          type="Microsoft.ServiceBus.Configuration.WebHttpRelayBindingCollectionElement, Microsoft.ServiceBus, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <add name="ws2007HttpRelayBinding"
          type="Microsoft.ServiceBus.Configuration.WS2007HttpRelayBindingCollectionElement, Microsoft.ServiceBus, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <add name="netTcpRelayBinding"
          type="Microsoft.ServiceBus.Configuration.NetTcpRelayBindingCollectionElement, Microsoft.ServiceBus, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <add name="netOnewayRelayBinding"
          type="Microsoft.ServiceBus.Configuration.NetOnewayRelayBindingCollectionElement, Microsoft.ServiceBus, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <add name="netEventRelayBinding"
          type="Microsoft.ServiceBus.Configuration.NetEventRelayBindingCollectionElement, Microsoft.ServiceBus, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <add name="netMessagingBinding"
          type="Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Configuration.NetMessagingBindingCollectionElement, Microsoft.ServiceBus, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
      </bindingExtensions>
    </extensions>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Thanks Sidney, this is exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is to set up an Azure Hybrid Connection which is built for the exact thing that you are trying to do:

Here is an intro:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/integration-hybrid-connection-overview/

Here is how to set it up:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/integration-hybrid-connection-create-manage/

Comment: That's what we used to talk to our on-prem services from Azure